# Elasticsearch 8: new OOM kills in comparison with ES7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-8

We test Elasticsearch 8.7.0 cluster setup (to migrate from ES 7.17.9)
and we face the problem that the **voting-only node** in the testing cluster
is sometimes **killed by OOM**.

We use almost identical setup like in our current production ES7 cluster,
where we never encounter OOM, which is quite weird.

ES7 setup (never encounter OOM):

- **Version:** Elasticsearch 7.17.9
- **OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, kernel: 5.15.0-1030-aws
- **Hardware (EC2)**:
  2x r6g.large (arm64, 2 vCPU, 16 GiB RAM) (data nodes)
  *1x t4g.small (arm64, 2 vCPU, 2 GiB RAM) (**voting-only node**)*
- **amazon-cloudwatch-agent:** version 1.247357.0b252275

ES8 setup (sometimes encounter OOM on the voting-only node)

- **Version:** Elasticsearch 8.7.0
- **OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, kernel: 5.15.0-1031-aws
- **Hardware (EC2):**
  2x r6g.large (arm64, 2 vCPU, 16 GiB RAM) (data nodes)
  *1x t4g.small (arm64, 2 vCPU, 2 GiB RAM) (**voting-only node**)*
- **amazon-cloudwatch-agent:** version 1.247358.0b252413

The only other application running on nodes is amazon-cloudwatch-agent for
collection of logs and metrics, which has the same memory footprint.

Also, the memory footprint of both Elasticsearch instances on voting-only nodes
is similar, but not entirely the same (ES8 node spawns two processes):

**ES7 production setup memory footprint:**
elastic+ process **78.6% RAM**
**ES8 testing setup memory footprint:**
elastic+ process **79.9% RAM**
elastic+ process **4.7% RAM**

We could increase RAM for the voting-only node to 4GB, but first we would like to know more
what is going on.

Do you think Elasticsearch 8 or it's bundled Java could cause newly encountered
invocations of OOM killer?

I asked this question also on Elasticsearch [Discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-8-new-oom-kills-in-comparison-with-es7/330016), which lead in interesting discussion, but to extend the audience I am reposting it also here.